# R : Error in lognet(x, is.sparse, ix, jx, y, weights, offset, alpha, nobs, : one multinomial or binomial class has 1 or 0 observations; not allowed

Tags: r, logistic-regression, sentiment-analysis, word2vec

I am trying to do a sentiment analysis systeme using word2vec and multinomial logistic regression;

Here below the R code :

```
library(tidyverse)
library(text2vec)
library(caret)
library(glmnet)
library(ggrepel)

Train_classifier <- read.csv('IRC2.csv',header=T, sep=";")


# select only 4 column of the dataframe

Train <- Train_classifier[, c("Note.Reco", "Raison.Reco", "DATE_SAISIE", "idpart")]

#delete rows with empty value columns
subTrain <- Train[rowSums(Train == '') == 0,]
subTrain$ID <- seq.int(nrow(subTrain))

# # replacing class values
subTrain$Note.Reco = ifelse(subTrain$Note.Reco >= 0 & subTrain$Note.Reco <= 4, 0, ifelse(subTrain$Note.Reco >= 5 &
subTrain$Note.Reco <= 6, 1, ifelse(subTrain$Note.Reco >= 7 & subTrain$Note.Reco <= 8, 2, 3)))



#Data pre processing
#Doc2Vec

prep_fun <- tolower
tok_fun <- word_tokenizer

subTrain[] <- lapply(subTrain, as.character)

reason <- subTrain[['Raison.Reco']][1:10]


it_train <- itoken(subTrain$Raison.Reco, 
                   preprocessor = prep_fun, 
                   tokenizer = tok_fun,
                   ids = subTrain$ID,
                   progressbar = TRUE)





#creation of vocabulary and term document matrix
  ### fichier  d'apprentissage
vocab <- create_vocabulary(it_train)
vectorizer <- vocab_vectorizer(vocab)
dtm_train <- create_dtm(it_train, vectorizer)




##Define  tf-idf model 

tfidf <- TfIdf$new()
# fit the model to the train data and transform it with the fitted model
dtm_train_tfidf <- fit_transform(dtm_train, tfidf)


glmnet_classifier <- cv.glmnet(x = dtm_train_tfidf,
                               y = subTrain[['Note.Reco']], family = 'multinomial',type.multinomial = "grouped")


#plot(glmnet_classifier)
```

Here the structure of the datframe SubTrain :

```
Note.Reco Raison.Reco DATE_SAISIE idpart ID
2 3 Toujours bien suivi par mon conseiller 19/03/2014 102853645 1
3 2 Bon accueil 19/03/2014 1072309 2
4 3 je suis satisfaite 19/03/2014 191391 3
6 1 satisfait !! 19/03/2014 14529 4
7 3 satisfait de ma conseillère 19/03/2014 100065501 5
```

But when I run this code I get this error :

```
> glmnet_classifier <- cv.glmnet(x = dtm_train_tfidf,
+                                y = subTrain[['Note.Reco']], family = 'multinomial',type.multinomial = "grouped")
Error in lognet(x, is.sparse, ix, jx, y, weights, offset, alpha, nobs,  : 
  one multinomial or binomial class has 1 or 0 observations; not allowed
```

As you can see in the dataframe i have no column with 0 and 1  values so I don't why I get this error.

Can you help me to solve this problem?

thank you

Comment: I think the error refers there being only one observation of one of the multinominal states. have you summarized your data to see how many observations in each multinonimal category you have?

Comment: Thank you, how can I do with R to summarize my data?

Comment: Actually reading you code it seems that the comments are your dependent variable? The comments are unique so it really does not make much sense to run a multinominal regression here, or am i missing something?

Comment: You wrote **datframe SubTrain** and `y = subTrain[[...`. Do you have a typo?

Comment: @yoland yes it is true what you understand, so in this case I make a binomial?

Comment: no i think in that case you read the comments and try to classify them and then run a regression. or look for another research method. in any case this is not a programming problem

Comment: Ok thank you, just last question please, in which case we do a multinomial logistic regression?

Comment: @yoland I think what I did is not false corresponding to what I read in this course [link](https://web.stanford.edu/~jurafsky/slp3/7.pdf)  `"Technically, logistic regression refers to a classifier that classifies
an observation into one of two classes, and multinomial logistic regression is used when classifying into more than two classes, although informally and in this chapter we sometimes use the shorthand logistic regression even when we are talking about
multiple classes." `